# Aligning ExPex interlinear glosses in multicol environment

Tags: multicol, linguistics, expex

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\ex %1
    \begingl
        \gla ŋada baniñu //
        \glb {I (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc 1SG.NOM coming //
        \glft `I am coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %2
    \begingl
        \gla ŋinda baniñu //
        \glb {you (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc 2SG.NOM coming //
        \glft `You are coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %3
    \begingl
        \gla {balan dugumbil} baniñu //
        \glb {the woman (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc {the woman.ABS} coming //
        \glft `The woman is coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %4
    \begingl
        \gla {bayi yara} baniñu //
        \glb {the man (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc {the man.ABS} coming //
        \glft `The man is coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %5
    \begingl
        \gla ŋada ŋinu-na balgan //
        \glb {I (AGT)} {you (PAT)} hitting //
        \glc 1SG.NOM 2SG-ACC hitting //
        \glft `I'm hitting you.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %6
    \begingl
        \gla ŋinda ŋaygu-na balgan //
        \glb {you (AGT)} {me (PAT)} hitting //
        \glc 2SG.NOM 1SG-ACC hitting //
        \glft `You're hitting me.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Even though the individual examples all have the same number of lines and also have both upper and lowercase characters, the spacing between them is off when put side by side in two columns, which looks awkward:

[image: Awkward spacing between examples in multicol environment]

Is there any way I can fix this? Interestingly, leaving out the last two examples, I don't get any irregular aligning.

Comment: This compiles with no spacing problem for me. What TeX distribution are you using? You may have some outdated packages.

Comment: Texlive 2013 it would seem, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

`expex` issues an `\noindent` at the end of `\xe`. Imho if would be better to use (like lists) `\@doendpe`. (There is no need to load xunicode in a current system, and xltxtra is often unnecessary too so I remove both).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{expex}

\makeatletter
\def\xe{%
   \expandafter\vskip\lingbelowexskip
   \egroup
   \if@specialexno \else \stepexcnt \fi
   \allowbreak
   \prevdepth\dp\strutbox
   %\noindent
   \@doendpe
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}%\raggedcolumns

\ex %1
    \begingl
        \gla ŋada baniñu //
        \glb {I (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc 1SG.NOM coming //
        \glft `I am coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %2
    \begingl
        \gla ŋinda baniñu //
        \glb {you (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc 2SG.NOM coming //
        \glft `You are coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %3
    \begingl
        \gla {balan dugumbil} baniñu //
        \glb {the woman (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc {the woman.ABS} coming //
        \glft `The woman is coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %4
    \begingl
        \gla {bayi yara} baniñu //
        \glb {the man (S/AGT)} coming //
        \glc {the man.ABS} coming //
        \glft `The man is coming.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %5
    \begingl
        \gla ŋada ŋinu-na balgan //
        \glb {I (AGT)} {you (PAT)} hitting //
        \glc 1SG.NOM 2SG-ACC hitting //
        \glft `I'm hitting you.' //
    \endgl
\xe

\ex %6
    \begingl
        \gla ŋinda ŋaygu-na balgan //
        \glb {you (AGT)} {me (PAT)} hitting //
        \glc 2SG.NOM 1SG-ACC hitting //
        \glft `You're hitting me.'//
    \endgl
\xe

\end{multicols}
blblabla
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my actual homework document, the spacing is still off. Maybe it's due to some interference with some other plugin or small caps from `leipzig`?!

Comment: Sorry but what answer do you expect to your comment? Without any code one can guess.

Comment: @Ulrike I assume you were able to reproduce the original behaviour? I wasn't.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I can reproduce it with miktex + TL15 which both have the newest latex and the newest multicol. With TL14 I don't see the behaviour.

Comment: OK, sorry if I wasn't clear. I should have posted the code. Find the whole source here: http://pastebin.com/0k2ymqL6 – as I said, I'm currently using Texlive 2013, which is what the current Ubuntu LTS comes with by default; backports sadly aren't offered as it looks like.

(EDIT: Changed link to code that should compile – I had cut too much out that I thought wasn't necessary.)

Comment: OK, I just updated my TL distribution to 2014 after all by finally upgrading Ubuntu to the current version, and now there's no problem anymore, as @AlanMunn said.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I could "fix" this by replacing `multicols` with `multicols*` and a manual `\columnbreak` after the 3rd example, with a `\vfill` right before it and at the end of the environment. This seems a little hackish, though.